# (swift) wnwrappingできないオプションバリュー

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode 6.4を使用しています。

iPhoneのバックカメラの映像をAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayerクラスのframeに表示するプログラムを書いていますが、

```
var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: error) as AVCaptureInput
```

上記の太字の行で

> ViewController.swift:53:115: 'AnyObject!' is not convertible to
>   'AVCaptureInput'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

というエラーが発生します。

そしてasをas!にしましたが今度は同じ行で
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
というエラーが発生します。

一応、その前のプログラムも添付しておきます。（サンプルプログラムのままです）

```
func configureCamera() -> Bool {
    // init camera device
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var devices: NSArray = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    // find back camera
    for device: AnyObject in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {
            captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
        }
    }

    if (captureDevice != nil) {
        // Debug
        println(captureDevice!.localizedName)
        println(captureDevice!.modelID)
    } else {
        println("Missing Camera")
        return false
    }

    // init device input
    var error: NSErrorPointer!
    var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: error) as! AVCaptureInput

    self.stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
}
```

Comment: `var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput? = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: error) as? AVCaptureInput`じゃないですか？

Comment: as?にすると、(パス名)/ViewController.swift:53:115: Value of optional type 'AVCaptureInput?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?　というエラーが発生します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unwrap に失敗するであろう箇所が二つあります：

```
// init device input
var error: NSErrorPointer!
var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: error) as! AVCaptureInput
```

まず、`error` 変数を初期化せずに `deviceInputWithDevice` に渡しています。

エラー情報を受け取る場合は、ドキュメントで紹介されている方法を使われることをお勧めします。以下が基本的なパターンです：

```
var error: NSError?
let result = foo(param, &error)
```

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_7)

---

もう一つは、`deviceInputWithDevice` の返り値の型が `AnyObject!`となっているのですが、ヘッダのコメントによると、nil を返すこともあるようです。

よって `as! AVCaptureInput` のような強制 unwrap は失敗する可能性があります。

```
var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput? = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: error) as? AVCaptureInput
```

としてください。

Comment: `var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput? = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: error) as? AVCaptureInput`
としましたが、
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
というエラーが発生しました。別のサンプルコードも試してみます。

Comment: 一箇所目も直されていれば、少なくとも `deviceInputWithDevice` ではエラーが発生しないと思うのですが、いかがでしょう？

Comment: var error: NSError?
        var deviceInput: AVCaptureInput? = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: &error) as? AVCaptureInput
できました。ありがとうございます。